# Two strings reference the same value?

Tags: javascript

`var a = 'a';
var anotherA = 'a';`

Even though JS returns `true` when `a == anotherA` or `a === anotherA`, do both variables actually point to the **same** location in memory?

Comment: Your answer is __No__

Comment: String literals are *probably* interned, but it's not guaranteed. Second of all, *why would you care*? JavaScript is such a high-level language you should not be thinking about "memory locations" with respect to string literals.

Comment: @AlexisKing JavaScript is used in various areas, not exactly inside browsers but on Lego Brick for example. In that case the question is perfectly valid. But it is implementation dependent, yes.

Comment: @c-smile JavaScript does not allow you to even access memory location semantics. Thinking about things like this in JavaScript is a waste of time. Optimize the code your profiler tells you to, not *string literals*.

Comment: @AlexisKing I am not sure I understand relation between "language" and "memory location semantics".  If JS String class would have method `addressOf()` will it change nature of the language itself? Think about asm.js and the like.

Answer (score 1):

They're equal in value, but there is no guarantee that they point to the same piece of memory.

Answer (score 0):

They are not storing in same memory address because every variable create in JS without reference point new memory address.
In here, You only compare value. For comparing value you actually follow the ECMA-262

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: What is "a new memory space" exactly?